# How to get type custom error class typescript?

Tags: typescript

I build custom error class with typescript :

```
class AppError extends Error{
    constructor(message: string, statusCode: Number){
        super(<string>message);

        this["statusCode"] = statusCode,
        this["status"] = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' :'error'
        this["isOperational"] = true;
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    }
}
```

I use this error handling:

```
app.all('*', (req: Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction)=>{
    next(new AppError(`Can\'t find ${req.originalUrl} on this server`, 404))
})
```

Here problem. How to get type `AppError` class. I build error handler middleware:

```
const errorHandler = (err: Error, req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction)=>{
    console.log(err)
    res.status(res.statusCode).json(err.message)
}
```

How to add `AppError` type `err` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `err` parameter must remain as `Error` because this handler can be used with any type of error, not just `AppError`.

What you can do is check if the given `err` is an instance of `AppError` as such:

```
const errorHandler = (err: Error, req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) => {
    if (err instanceof AppError) {
      // err is an AppError
      console.log(err)
      res.status(res.statusCode).json(err.message)
    } else {
      // do some other thing here, err is not an AppError
    }
}
```